# create a div that dynamically stretches vertically as browser window changes

Tags: css, html, dynamic

Is this possible? Essentially I'm trying to create a div layout that looks like:

```
<div_wrapper>

    <div_header>
    </div_header>

    <div_content>
    </div_content>

</div_wrapper>
```

Where upon page load, the div_header occupies 200px, and the div_content fills the remaining vertical space. And also, as the browser changes sizes (ie, user drags corner of browser to resize), the div_header still remains at 200px, which the div_content dynamically changes sizes.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any problem with div_header () just create a css rules that states:

```
#header{height:200px;}
```

you can use js to resize you content (). If you include jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
         $('#content').css("height", ($(window).height() - 200) + "px");
     });
     $('#content').css("height", ($(window).height() - 200) + "px");
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wezzy, damn you're awesome. I spent a good 4 hours on this before you stepped in. One quick question though, could you explain why the $(window).resize(function(){...} is necessary to keep the modifications to the div window dynamic? Is it a way to make an active listener? Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 3):

This should do it..

```
#wrapper{height:100%;}
#header{
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#content{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Gaby, thanks for your response, but it with this solution, the content would be 100% of the original window size. It wouldn't be dynamic. Thanks! Matt